# Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016

Tags: ios, http, https

I've read many blogs and discussion regrading "**Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016"** but still i'm not sure this security check is only for "**APPLE APP Store**" app or it will also be applied on enterprise app which usually don't submit on app store.

I've an enterprise app which is using some Http connections that can not be easily migrated to Https.

So what about this situation ? App will shut down or it will be normally working ?

Some reference Links : [link1](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/) , [link2](https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/15/ats-https-ios-apps/) , [link3](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/wwdc-2016-apple-to-require-https-encryption-on-all-ios-apps-by-2017/) , [link4](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979)

Answer (score 1):

Apple still requires Https connection but currently we have option to bypass Transport Security through app  info plist. I think in future that option will stop working totally so it will be must to upgrade your server to secure server.

Comment: OP is asking for enterprise application specifically!

Comment: Yes. will we be able to bypass Transport security check in 2017 too? still i've not read any authenticated link who says "APPLE will stop supporting http in 2017".I'm just looking forward to one authenticated document who will be bit clear like binary, Either supporting HTTP connection or not supporting HTTP connections.